# browserify: command not found

Tags: node.js, browserify, node-modules, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is really getting on my nerves. I have installed browserify using `yarn global add browserify`, and then I tried using `browserify`, `browserify -h` and `browserify -v`. None of them are working. I know that there are plenty of solutions out there for this, but none of them are working. I'm using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, and my `.bashrc` file contains

```
echo Hello World!
PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin/
```

I've been executing `yarn global add browserify` and `yarn global remove browserify` so many times. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to

1. Run `npm config set prefix /usr/local`
2. Install the global dependency with `npm i -g` format instead of yarn.

I now have a new question, however. When I try to install with yarn after setting the prefix, it fails, giving me the error `yarn error Cannot create /usr/local/bin/ due to insufficient permissions.` I don't have many global dependencies, so it's not a huge deal, but does anyone know why it's working for npm but not yarn?

Answer (score 0):

```
PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin/
```

This sets the PATH variable *inside* the .bashrc script, but doesn't export it to the outside environment. If you try to run

```
echo $PATH
```

in a new shell, you'll (probably) not see the `.npm-global/bin` value in there.

To expose variables to the environment, you need to use `export`:

```
export PATH="~/.npm-global/bin/:$PATH"
```

(Enclosing it in quotes is necessary in case $PATH already contains a value with spaces. The order is a personal preference, I guess)